# select a single item in checkbox list using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a checkboxlist in asp.net page and bound data from database. Now i want to select the single item. Suppose i select an item means clear the old selection and select the new items only

Please help me to do this..

Comment: Would it not be a whole lot easier just to use radiobuttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

**Front end**

```
function radioMe(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var sender = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (sender.nodeName != 'INPUT') return;
  var checker = sender;
  var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= chks.ClientID %>');
  var chks = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
      if (chks[i] != checker)
      chks[i].checked = false;
  }
}

<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chks">
  <asp:ListItem>Item</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Item</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Item</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Item</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**Back end**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        chks.Attributes.Add("onclick", "radioMe(event);");
}
```

But instead of doing all this you should consider `RadioButtonList` control

Comment: Pardon i did it in IE not working in FF yet, let me check it.

Answer (score 5):

Using a CheckBoxList over a RadioButtonList can be handy sometimes as it allows a user to unselect a choice without me having to invent a work-around. Following yogi's answer I wanted an approach that allowed easy reuse without having to plug in a ClientID of the CheckBoxList into the function for each use. Thanks for the template yogi.

- Usage:

  ```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="m_testControl" runat="server" data-toggle="radio" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
      <asp:ListItem Value="CON">Concur</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="CWI">Concur With Intent</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="DNC">Do Not Concur</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
  ```
- JQuery Function:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
      // turn all CheckBoxLists labeled for 'radio' to be single-select
      $('[data-toggle=radio]').each(function ()
      {
          var clientId = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).find('input').each(function ()
          {
              // set parent's id
              $(this).attr('data-parent', clientId);

              // add an onclick to each input
              $(this).click(function (e)
              {
                  // ensure proper event
                  if (!e) e = window.event;
                  var sender = e.target || e.srcElement;
                  if (sender.nodeName != 'INPUT') return;


                  // toggle off siblings
                  var id = $(this).attr('id');
                  var parent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
                  $('input[data-parent=' + parent + ']').not('#' + id).prop('checked', false);
              });
          });
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `RadioButtonList` would fit better, as it only lets you select a single element.

[ASP.NET RadioButtonList Control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_radiobuttonlist.asp)

Radio-Buttonlist [Sample](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_radiobuttonlist)

[RadioButtonList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
           var chks = document.getElementById('<%= chkBranchRoleTransaction.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
            for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                    chks[i].checked = false;
            }
            $(this)[0].checked = true;
       });
        // or//
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
             var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= chkBranchRoleTransaction.ClientID %>');
            var chks = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
             for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                 chks[i].checked = false;
             }
             $(this)[0].checked = true;
         });
    });[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzaaz.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = "";
$("#CblProduct").on('click', ':checkbox', function () {       
    if (id != "")
    {
        $(id).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
    if($("#CblProduct").length > 0)
    {
        id = this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int indexOfL=0;// the index of initial selected item
    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {    
            {
                if (i != indexOfL && li.Selected)
                {    
                    indexOfL=i;
                    CheckBoxList1.ClearSelection();
                    li.Selected = true;

                }
                i++;
            }
        }}
```

i"m saving the index of selected item and when there is a change we get two selected items so with help of indexOfL we get the right item to keep.
i don"t know if this approach is the best because this code runs in the server side....
hope it helps...