# Repeater control checkbox event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

Am having three check box in repeater control. I need the concept like radio button list.When i click the first row first checkbox, other two are checked property is set to false. suppose i check the second one means first and third are unchecked.

**My Design code is here :**

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterItems" runat="server" 
                                                                    onitemdatabound="repeaterItems_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
       <table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
          <tr>
               <td style="width: 18px;">
               <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("fld_id")%>'></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td style="width: 301px;">
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("fld_Question")%>'></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td style="width: 10px;">   
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
               </td>
               <td style="width: 30px;">
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged"/>
               </td>
               <td style="width: 33px;">
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged"/>
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

**code is :**

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk1 = sender as CheckBox;
        RepeaterItem item = chk1.Parent as RepeaterItem;
        CheckBox chk2 = item.FindControl("CheckBox2") as CheckBox;
        chk2.Checked = false;
    }

    protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void repeaterItems_ItemCreated1(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;

        if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox1_CheckedChanged);
        }
    }
```

CheckBox1_CheckedChanged event not fire. Please help me to fix this error.
I spent more time to solve this issue but i can't..

Comment: What do you want to do on check box check change. Want to check another check box in the repeater. For this you should either use java-script or jQuery.

Comment: you can do it with jquery.. please refer to the following link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687370/select-a-single-item-in-checkbox-list-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that you are not binding the repeater on post back, and that viewstate is enabled on the repeater.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   Repeater.Datasource = dataset(what ever source);
   Repeater.Databind;
}
```

There is no reason why you should bind to the itemcreated event on the repeater, just to attach to the oncheckedchanged event, as this is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by also JQuery

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.chkGroup').change(function () {
                var parentTr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var currentCheckID = $(this).find('input').attr("id");
                $(parentTr).find('.chkGroup input').each(function () {
                    if (currentCheckID != $(this).attr("id")) {

                        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterItems" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repeaterItems_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 18px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 301px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10px;">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" CssClass="chkGroup" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" CssClass="chkGroup" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 33px;">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" CssClass="chkGroup" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: are you set JQuery link and class where needed in repeaterItems's checkbox?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same event `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` handler for all the three check-boxes `OnCheckedChanged`.
By using the sender object you could know which checkbox raised the event and then set the other two check-boxes `checked` property to `false.`

Comment: This does not answer the question